# Correct words to use in a From certain date to certain date doing something

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles, dates

So this is what I could come up with, but for some reason, it sounds wrong to me, and it is bugging me

> As of 29.05.2023. **Through and including the** 29.08.2023, **we will have new** regulations in temporary emergency effect.

Bold text is what I think is wrong, but all googling points to correct, but it sounds off to me for some reason. Formal English, as this is for an official document

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Don't overthink this one. *I worked Monday through [to] Friday last week* unambiguously specifies an ***inclusive*** range of days / dates. In your case, *From 29.05.2023 through 29.08.2023 temporary new emergency regulations will be in effect.*

Comment: "all googling points to correct" This does not count as demonstrating adequate research. What actually told you that this was correct? Was a reason provided?

Comment: You could say "From 29.05.2023 to 29.08.20203 inclusive there will be new, temporary, emergency regulations in effect." The words in the second part of the sentence appear jumbled to me. which makes it sound wrong to a native BrE speaker